# creating a cql filter in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, postgis, geoserver

Please could I gain some assistance with the following problem. I would like to create a CQL filter in leaflet which filters data from GeoServer, with the data hosted in a PostGIS database.

For example, selecting a reservoir name from the NAME field in the database.The filter will be variable as the user can enter different names through an input dialog field.

I am displaying my layers as WMS, and although I was able to get an interactive filter working in openlayers 3, I still have had no like with leaflet.

I am new to the web development side of GIS and any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Cameron

Comment: Hello Cameron, please try to post the code (e.g. in a jsfiddle) you're working with. This makes it easier for people to help you. Also, try to describe specifically what you have tried (with references to your code ideally) and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In leaflet you use TileLayer.WMS to plot wms layer on map.  like this:

```
var nexrad = L.tileLayer.wms("http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi", {
    layers: 'nexrad-n0r-900913',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: "Weather data © 2012 IEM Nexrad"
});
```

You see some standard leaflet WMS options there like format, version ..crs etc.

But leaflet send all extra parameters/options in url to support [non-standard WMS parameter](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html) . CQL_FILTER is one of them, so what you need to do is supply cql_filter options (column name is case sensitive):

```
var nexrad = L.tileLayer.wms("http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi", {
    layers: 'nexrad-n0r-900913',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    cql_filter: 'NAME=filterhere'
    attribution: "Weather data © 2012 IEM Nexrad"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time posting to the forum and already I have received great help!

I have managed to get the cql_filter as suggested within my code as below:

```
var contours = L.tileLayer.wms('http://gis01-dbn:8080/geoserver/Inyaninga_243-198/wms', {
        layers: 'Inyaninga_243-198:contours_3857',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        cql_filter: 'elevation= 126', 
        });
```

Is there however any way to make this elevation parameter receive user input and update?

I have created a form in the html as such:

```
 <form>
    Elevation(m):<br>
   <input type="text" id="myInput">
   <input type="button" value="Elevation">
</form>
```

However, I am getting stuck with passing "myInput" into the cql_filter to accept a value which the user can enter.

I have tried creating a function housing the cql_filter but again cannot call this into the cql_filter option when loading the WMS.